# HTTP wget between Amazon instances

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to Amazon EC2.

1. I have 2 instances A and B in EC2. Both are Redhat 6.4.
2. They are part of the same VPC
3. A is assigned with an Elastic IP.
4. I setup an Apache httpd server on A to download files from.
5. I made sure to have an inbound rule on A for HTTP traffic(port 80). IPtables on A is stopped as well

I am trying to download a file from A on machine B.

Here is what i get:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-21-183 tmp]$ wget http://ec2-1-2-3-4.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/MySQL-5.6.15-1.el6.x86_64.rpm-bundle.tar
--2014-04-24 08:36:32--  http://ec2-1-2-3-4.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/MySQL-5.6.15-1.el6.x86_64.rpm-bundle.tar
Resolving ec2-1-2-3-4.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com... 172.31.6.188
Connecting to ec2-1-2-3-4.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com|172.31.6.188|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2014-04-24 08:36:32 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

It seems i am missing something basic. What's is wrong in the above setup?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Error 403 is an HTTP error - it means that B was able to successfully connect to A, but httpd returned an access error. 
Check your httpd configuration - you may have configured it to require authentication for all requests, or the file itself may have file access permissions that do not allow httpd to access it.

Comment: Thx for answering, I found that the problem at the end was because SELinux was configured on in A